# apply conditional formatting to a cell when it matches the text in another column on another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of accounts in column a of sheet one.
I have a sublist of the same accounts in column a of sheet two.
If the account name in column a of sheet 1 matches an account name in column a of sheet two I want the account name of sheet one to hi-light in orange.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking for but this might work for you or get you on the right track.

1. In Sheet1, define the area where you have your account numbers with a Name. This will help avoid cell reference issues.
2. In Sheet2, select all cells in the area where you want your conditional formatting to be applied.
3. Choose Format, Conditional Formatting and click the **+** to add a new formatting rule
4. For Style, choose Classic and "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
5. Here you can either do a cell for cell match, like

> =if(Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A2,"match")

or use VLOOKUP to search within the named area of step 2, like

> =vlookup(*a_cell_within_your_range*,*SECTION_NAME*,1,FALSE)

6. Choose a color scheme for your match and hit OK.

As long as the formula yields a positive output, the formatting rule will apply. Hope this helps.